# Perl Text To Code Ratio

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm looking for a way to determine the code to text ratio of a web page in Perl. Not looking for anything complex just a simple print out like HTML Code:75% Text:25% just for SEO Reasons.

Comment: I would like to take a webpage as a file, place into a variable and the determine the percentage that is HTML code and the percentage that is visible text.

Comment: HTML tags are rarely "code". How about using the term "markup"?

Comment: HTML tags are always "code". They aren't "program code" but they are "code". (As is ROT13)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hmm...  thinking quickly...  How about:

```
my $htmllength = 0;
my $textlength = 0;
while(<>) {
    s/(<[^>]*>)/$htmllength += length($1); "";/eg;
    $textlength += length($_);
}

print "HTML Code: " . (100 * $htmllength / ($htmllength + $textlength)) . "\n";
print "Text     : " . (100 * $textlength / ($htmllength + $textlength)) . "\n";
```

You can then simply run the script on the file(s) in question:

```
perl SCRIPT file1.html file2.html
```

**NOTE: this will not work if your data contains any CDATA fields**

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/119280)!

Comment: Nope, but I'm not parsing it either.  However, I am letting content through that may otherwise be invisible to the presentation.

Comment: Thanks for all the negative votes!  Show me a file that it fails with and I'll delete the post!

Comment: at a random guess, try CDATA element with ">" in the text.

Comment: Drat.  I always forget about CDATA.

Comment: It will also treat inline CSS and JS as text content.

Comment: It will also add extra markup-as-content if there is a `>` character in an attribute value.

Answer (score 4):

Use HTML::TreeBuilder to strip out the text.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $content = get(shift @ARGV);
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;

my $text = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($content)->as_text;

my $html_size = length $content;
my $text_size = length $text;
my $percentage = 100 * ( $text_size / $html_size );

say qq[$percentage%];
```

Comment: Seems to handle them fine based on a quick test I just ran.